# Prevent deadlock in read-committed SELECT

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssis, deadlock, read-committed

I am extracting data from a business system supplied by a third party to use in reporting. I am using a single SELECT statement issued from an SSIS data flow task source component that joins across multiple tables in the source system to create the dataset I want. We are using the default read-committed isolation level.

To my surprise I regularly find this extraction query is deadlocking and being selected as the victim. I didn't think a SELECT in a read-committed transaction could do this, but according to this SO answer it *is* possible: [Can a readcommitted isolation level ever result in a deadlock (Sql Server)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19595115/can-a-readcommitted-isolation-level-ever-result-in-a-deadlock-sql-server)

Through the use of the trace flags 1204 and 12222 I've identified the conflicting statement, and the object and index in question. Essentially, the contention is over a data page in the primary key of one of the tables. I need to extract from this table using a join on its key (so I'm taking out an S lock), the conflicting statement is performing an INSERT and is requesting an IX lock on the index data page.

(Side note: the above SO talks about this issue occurring with *non-clustered* indexes, but this appears to be occurring in the clustered PK. At least, that is what I believe based on my interpretation of the deadlock information in the event log and the "associatedObjectId" property.)

Here are my constraints:

1. The conflicting statement is in an encrypted stored procedure supplied by a third party as part of off-the-shelf software. There is no possibility of getting the plaintext code or having it changed.
2. I don't want to use dirty-reads as I need my extracted data to maintain its integrity.
3. It's not clear to me how or if restructuring my extract query could prevent this. The lock is on the PK of the table I'm most interested in, and I can't see any alternatives to using the PK.
4. I don't mind my extract query being the victim as I prefer this over interrupting the operational use of the source system. However, this does cause the SSIS execution to fail, so if it must be this way I'd like a cleaner, more graceful way to handle this situation.

Can anyone suggestion ways to, preferably, prevent the deadlock, or if not, then handle the error better?

Comment: Consider using a snapshot isolation transaction to avoid data reads and the deadlock.

Comment: What specific SSIS components, i.e. OLE DB source/destination, Execute SQL Task, etc., are leading to the deadlocks?

Comment: Thanks @DanGuzman, reading up on that I think it would work, although I think there would be concerns it might impact the support of the business system to change database settings (even though setting snapshot isolation on should not affect the existing queries) and the impact on tempdb size.

Comment: @userfl89 Yes, it is an OLE DB source within a DFT. The other query involved in the deadlock is from the third party application, not from SSIS.

Comment: @GreatApe, yes, turning on the database `ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION` will increase tempdb usage and incur additional overhead of 14 bytes per row. The benefits outweigh the overhead in many cases.

Comment: Have you tried utilizing the READPAST Hint?

Comment: Hi @MichaelG, thank you for the suggestion. It some scenarios that might work, certainly. I'm extracting using a time window which ought to be up to "now" (at the beginning of the extract process) so I need to work out if skipping locked records would break the integrity of my extracted data set or not.

This raises an interesting point, which is that if skipping these records is not appropriate then that _might_ also apply in the case of snapshot isolation (if the snapshot isolates new records that would be in the time window.)

Comment: @DanGuzman would a lighter-weight solution be to use a serializable transaction isolation level for the extract query? Assuming it executes in an adequately short period of time it shouldn't block the operational use of the source system without having the overhead of row versioning in the tempdb.

Comment: @GreatApe, serializable is generally more prone to deadlocks and blocking than read committed. That said, I agree it is a lighter weight solution and you could try it for your specific case.

Comment: I know this is an old post, but I just wanted to mention that there are ways to extract the encrypted sproc definition if you have sysadmin rights. Sproc encryption is mostly like "please don't look".

Answer (score 1):

My assumption here is that you are attempting to INSERT into the same table that you are SELECTing from. If no, then a screenshot of the data flow tab would be helpful in determining the problem. If yes, then you're in luck - I have had this problem before.

Add a sort to the data flow as this is a fully blocking transformation (see below regarding blocking transformations). What this means is that the SELECT will be required to complete loading all data into the pipeline buffer before any data is allowed to pass down to the destination. Otherwise, SSIS is attempting to INSERT data while there is a lock on the table/index. You might be able to get creative with your indexing strategies here (I have not tried this). But, a fully blocking transformation will do the trick and eliminates the need for any additional indexes to the table (and the overhead that entails).

Note: **never** use NOLOCK query hints when selecting data from a table as an attempt to get around this. I have never tried this nor do I intend to. You (the royal you) run the risk of ingesting uncommitted data into your ETL.

**Reference:**

https://jorgklein.com/2008/02/28/ssis-non-blocking-semi-blocking-and-fully-blocking-components/

Comment: Hi @j-weezy thank you for replying, although I think you have misunderstood the scenario. Only **my** SELECT is coming from SSIS. The conflicting INSERT is being issued by a third party application (see constraint 1)

Comment: @GreatApe I would reach out to the 3rd party application provider and let them know since it is their code that is causing the problem.

Comment: I suspect they would take the view that I'm the one causing the problem by executing queries against their database :)

Comment: @GreatApe You are at their mercy since the stored procedure is encrypted and it is their database - it might as well be a black box. Though, your comment in paragraph 3 regarding contention indicated a SELECT and INSERT to the same table. Otherwise, if other clients are hitting that vendor's database then that might be causing the DEADLOCK as well. I would still reach out and ask.